Are there any better methods to solve this problem?
The question is:
Given the function $ f(x) = (x + a) \ln(x + b) $, if $ f(x) \geq 0 $, what is the minimum value of $ a^2 + b^2 $?
A. $ \frac{1}{8} $
B. $ \frac{1}{4} $
C. $ \frac{1}{2} $
D. 1

My personal attempt is as follows:
Clear["`*"]
f[x_] := (x + a) Log[x + b]
f'[x]
{Limit[f'[x], x -> -b], Limit[f'[x], x -> +\[Infinity]]}
FunctionDomain[f'[x], x]
eq = f'[x0] == 0
i1 = (f[x0] /. Log[b + x0] -> -((a + x0)/(b + x0))) == 0 // 
  Reduce[#, x0] &
i2 = Log[b + x0] == 0 // Reduce[#, x0] &
e1 = Eliminate[{i1, i2}, x0]
Minimize[{a^2 + b^2, e1}, {a, b}]


The code above was derived from the following manual calculation process:
If $ f(x) = (x + a)\ln(x + b) \geq 0 $, then the minimum value of $ f(x) $ is greater than or equal to 0.
$$ f'(x) = \ln(x + b) + \frac{x + a}{x + b} = \ln(x + b) + 1 + \frac{a - b}{x + b} (x > -b), $$
Assuming $ a \geq b $, then $ x + a \geq x + b > 0 $,
When $ -b < x < -b + 1 $, $ \ln(x + b) < 0 $,
At this point, $ f(x) = (x + a)\ln(x + b) < 0 $, which does not satisfy the condition.
Therefore, $ a < b $ (Key point: Using the assumption method to prove the size relationship between $ a $ and $ b $, laying the groundwork for the subsequent analysis of the increase and decrease of $ f'(x) $).
Then $ f'(x) = \ln(x + b) + 1 + \frac{a - b}{x + b} (x > -b) $ is an increasing function in its domain.
Also, as $ x $ approaches $ -b $, $ f'(x) $ approaches $ \infty $, and as $ x $ approaches $ + \infty $, $ f'(x) $ approaches $ + \infty $,
So there exists $ x = x_0 $ such that $ f'(x_0) = 0 $, that is, $ \ln(x_0 + b) = -\frac{x_0 + a}{x_0 + b} $.
Thus, $ f(x) $ is decreasing on $ (-b, x_0) $ and increasing on $ (x_0, +\infty) $, so $ f(x) $ attains a minimal value at $ x = x_0 $, which is also the minimum value, so $ f(x)_{min} = $
$$ f(x_0) = (x_0 + a)\ln(x_0 + b) = (x_0 + a)\left(-\frac{x_0 + a}{x_0 + b}\right) = -\frac{(x_0 + a)^2}{x_0 + b} \leq 0, $$
and
$$ f(x_0) \geq 0, so \; x_0 = -a, $$
and $ \ln(x_0 + b) = -\frac{x_0 + a}{x_0 + b}, so \; \ln(b - a) = 0, $
thus $ b - a = 1 $, hence $ b = a + 1 $. Therefore, $ a^2 + b^2 = a^2 + (a + 1)^2 = $
$$ 2(a + \frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{1}{2}, $$
so the minimum value of $ a^2 + b^2 $ is $ \frac{1}{2} $.

Plesae write a more-informative title.

Function ForAll and Resolve help.
Minimize[{a^2 + b^2, 
  Resolve[ForAll[x, x > -b, (x + a) Log[x + b] >= 0], Reals]}, {a, b}]

